# How to have font size adapt itself to cell size?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a document where I use one sheet for presentation purposes. It's like a window/viewer of the content of the main sheet (the cell contents are all references to the main sheet). I built myself some navigation buttons, a delete button, and a search bar as well. When I project that sheet, it fills the screen nicely and makes the content a lot easier to read.

The issue is that the amount of text to be shown varies and does exceed the cell size in some cases. Ideally, I'd want the whole text to be visible without having to manually adapt the cell size and having to scroll. So for whenever there is more text than the cell allows to show, I'd like the font size to decrease enough for everything to become visible, and to adjust back when the cell contents change.

Perhaps this is too much for Google Sheets, in which case I'd be thankful for some pointers to what else I could use. Ideally, at least the data should remain in Google Sheets.